# Best practice to add extra attributes for an object that related only to a specific class

Tags: python, oop

I have the following class:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

I have a `class(Lobby)` that contain players.
The class should have extra attributes for each player.
for example, `idle` time:

```
class Lobby(object):
    def __init__(self, players):
        self.players = players
        for player in players:
            player.idle = 0
```

And I have another `class(Game)`
This class should have extra attributes for each player. For example, `team` attribute

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, players):
        self.players = players
        self.organize_teams();

    def organize_teams(self):
        for player in self.players:
            if condition1:
                player.team = 0
            elif condition2:
                player.team = 1
            elif condition3:
                player.team = 2
```

The problem is that the extra attributes of the player only related to the specific class.
so i thought about another way to do it.

for example, the Lobby class:

```
class Lobby(object):
    def __init__(self, players):
        self.players = {}
        for player in players:
            self.players[player] = {idle: 0}
```

Is it a good practice?

Comment: you need access player's team or teams' players? i.e. you can add teams structure to game, as for different games player can be in different teams

Comment: I don't want to add attributes to a player, because those attributes only relevant for the specific Game. (and there can be multiple games at a time). About the `team`, Im not using it as `int` (`player.team = 0`). thats just an example. I have `enum` for teams.

Comment: If things change from game to game, it might make sense to setup player creation using a Factory-style design pattern.

Comment: I think thats what I need, I will look into the `Factory` design pattern.

Comment: Your bottom solution is fine, just syntactically clunky.  Any improvements would just be to make the API clearer, you have the correct general approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you want to store values per instance of `Player`, but those values should be managed by the instance of `Game`. So different instances of `Game` can have different values for a certain `Player`. In that case, you just need a mapping between a `Player` and a value. That's just a `dict`. So I would propose the solution you show in `Lobby`.

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant.